# How to list the queries executed by BigQuery before or after a date?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

After an intense use of BigQuery, I needed to search a query executed weeks ago in the Query History but it didn't appear because was reached the max limit of queries that history can show. Is there a way to list executed queries in a time range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [INFORMATION_SCHEMA for Jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs), you can find your old query with a query!

```sql
SELECT query
FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_USER
WHERE
 job_type = "QUERY"
 AND end_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Even better, if you roughly remember part of your query text, you can search using LIKE, then you don't really need date filter:

```sql
...
WHERE query LIKE '%HeyMyKeyword%'
```

Comment: I like a lot your answer, after play a bit with it I found that even you can search by project that is very useful when you share datawarehouse with a lot of projects  with
`FROM region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT`
 and then specified the project with 
`WHERE user_email = "project@user_email"`

Comment: Glad that it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can see all the executed queries using the Cloud Shell of GCP. Find it at right top menu with a terminal icon.

[image]

Then in the shell run the next command to list the last 1000 executions (100,000 is the max limit)

```
bq ls -j -all -n 1000
```

If you need to look queries after or before a date, you need to convert your date to milliseconds and use this commands

```
bq ls -j --max_creation_time <YOUR_DATE_IN_MILISECONDS> -n <NUMBER_OF_QUERIES>

bq ls -j --max_creation_time 1587610800000 -n 10000

bq ls -j --min_creation_time 1587614400000 -n 10000
```

Reference https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference